# Is it possible to add a string before the value in ng-select?

Tags: angularjs, mixitup

I'm trying to add a string before the value in ng-select?

I'm using mixItup plugin and would like to have filer values in a drop down, but  mixitup required "." in the option value.

This is what I'm getting now:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="category" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories">
     <option label="Public" value="number:1">Public</option>
     <option label="Personal" value="number:2">Personal</option>
</select>
```

That is what I required:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="category" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories">
     <option label="Public" value=".cat-1">Public</option>
     <option label="Personal" value=".cat-2">Personal</option>
</select>
```

my code:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="category"
                    ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories">
</select>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use 
`ng-options="'.' + cat.id as cat.name for cat in categories"` 
http://jsfiddle.net/dp31o591/

Comment: Where you example answer exactly what I as for, the mixItUp doesn't work. I edited your jsFiddle to illustrate the issue.

Comment: My friend, your answer was: "I'm trying to add a string before the value in ng-select?". Did i answer on your question?

Comment: Yes you are right, will open another question, thanks